# : command not foundop/dominio.sh: line 2:

Tags: macos, sh

I'm writing shell scripting for Mac.
Here's my script:

```
echo "Bienvenido";
/Applications/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices;
sudo /Applications/sdk/platform-tools/adb  shell input text 'sp.soporte@gmail.com';
```

It realize the correct operation, but here is the output :

```
$ /Users/julien/Desktop/dominio.sh 
Bienvenido
: command not foundop/dominio.sh: line 1: 
List of devices attached 
4790057be1803096    device

: command not foundop/dominio.sh: line 2: 
: command not foundop/dominio.sh: line 3:
```

julien$

If I erase the ; it's not working any more. How should I do????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have Windows-style line endings in your script.

Unix-like systems, including MacOS, use a single LF character to terminate a line; Windows uses a CR-LF pair.

A Windows-style text file looks, on a Unix-like system, like ordinary text with an extra CR character at the end of each line.

Since you have a semicolon at the end of each line, this line:

```
echo "Bienvenido";
```

appears to the shell as two commands: `echo "Bienvenido"` and the CR character (which could actually be a command name if it existed). Note that the `echo` command was executed.

The shell prints an error message, something like:

```
/path/to/script: 1: CR: command not found
```

except that it prints the actual CR (carriage return) character, which moves the cursor to the beginning of the current line, overwriting part of the error message.

Translate your script to use Unix-style line endings. You can use `dos2unix` for this if you have it. (Read the man page; unlike most filter programs, it overwrites its input file by default.)

Incidentally, you don't need a semicolon on the end of each line of a shell script. Semicolons are needed only when you have multiple commands on one line.

Also, you should probably have a ["shebang"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) as the first line of your script, either `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` (use the latter if your script uses bash-specific features).

Comment: I just write it once again... my script were short, and no more pb ! The only thing is neither #!/bin/sh nor #!/bin/bash is accepted... but it doesn t give me any pb ! Tx

Comment: What do you mean by "neither `#!/bin/sh` nor `#!/bin/bash` is accepted"? What happens when you add it? Is there an error message? Also, how did you create the script file in the first place? An editor running under MacOS shouldn't use Windows-style line endings. Did you copy the script file from another system?